# Not recognized command split

Tags: r, split

I have a data set which i want to split into a testing and a validiation set. I have to do this because i have to build a prediction model. So I have to use this command.

I used the following code:

`split <- initial_split(train_data_down, prop = 3/4, strata = restatement)`

But when i runned it, i got the following code:

> 'split' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I have literaly no clue what to do, can anybody help me? I don't know what the error means and how to solve it

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal *reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Your example is certainly minimal, but it isn't reproducible.

Comment: Are you probably running this is terminal/command prompt instead of running it in the console?

Comment: `split` is also the name of an R function. You overwrite this function with a non function (`split` is a List, I guess). Try a different name for your variable "split", restart R and check if the problem persists.